# typescript error:2339. how can I use multiple types of object in one variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to make component with vanilla js + typescript

I made class "Component". the problem is "state"

```js
interface boardState {
  items: string[];
  page: number;
}
interface postState {
  writer: string;
  content: string;
}
class Component {
  $target : Element;
  state: boardState | postState;
  constructor() { ...}
  init() { ...}
  setState() { ...}
  render() { ...}
}
```

```
class Board extends Component{
  constructor(selector) {
    super(selector);
  }
  init(){
    this.state.items = ["title1", "title2"] ; // error
  }
}
```

and this is class "Board" extends Component.

I want to use different types of state.
ex) boardState, postState, pageState

but when i use `state.items` in Board the error occurred.

error message: TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'postState| boardState'.

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

that's because you only have `items` in `boardState`, what you need is do `type narrowing` and manage the case where items doesn't exist, in the TS documentation you can see more about that https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

but in your case, I think is better add the member in the Board class

Answer (score 0):

Can you just overr the type in the `Board` class?

e.g.

```
interface boardState {
  items: string[];
  page: number;
}
interface postState {
  writer: string;
  content: string;
}
class Component {
  $target : Element;
  state: boardState | postState;
}

class Board extends Component{
  state: boardState;
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  init(){
    this.state.items = ["title1", "title2"] ;
  }
}
```

https://typescript-bygs7m.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

`state` can either be `boardState` or `postState`, not both

In the case that it is `postState` and you attempt to set the value of `state.items`, it will not work, so TypeScript throws an error.